# SET instruction in SQL Server that doesn't work

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I've tried making some math operations in SQL Server and the code returns multiple values. I'm used to writing IN when handling multiple operations. However, as there is no where, I can't use IN. What to use?

```
use bio

update valori 
set lsd  in (select(max(valori) - min(valori)) / max(valori) from valori join param on 
valori.id_param=param.id_param
group by valori.id_param);
```

PS: Sorry if the question is not clear.

Comment: `SET {column} IN` isn't valid syntax. It's `SET {column} = `. What are you trying to do here, *"I'm used to writing IN when handling multiple operations"* doesn't make sense; a single row in column can only have ***one*** value, not many.

Comment: If you want to handle multiple values, you need to use a temporary table or a table variable. In both cases, you will use it like a regular table, doing INSERT INTO to add the values that the query returns. You can't assign multiple values to a scalar variable.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: You can't just write SQL however you want, and expect it to work.  You need to follow the syntax.  The syntax you have is not even valid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a correlated subquery and no `join`:

```
update valori 
    set lsd  = (select(max(valori) - min(valori)) / max(valori) valori 
                 from param 
                 where valori.id_param = param.id_param
                );
```

Of course, you set a value using `=`, not `in`.  I'm guessing that was just a typo of some sort.